# Returned messages from Wordpress contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form

I am using WPMail SMTP and Sendinblue.com to send email notifications from a contact form. Some of them are bouncing back but some are making it through, it's acting strange. When I logged into webmail for the email address I'm using to send the emails I found a lot of messages with this error:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
421 pEtCovMBY5n5ApEtCoO9cv - <forms@{domain}.com> message rejected AUP#SNDR:
retry timeout exceeded
```

We just migrated the hosting from Hostgator to Kinsta. The email is still through hostgator. The domain is registered through Godaddy and that's where the DNS records are. I know it's a mess. Any idea why this email is acting funky?

Comment: check mx records ? And to understand what is this error check this - https://www.courier.com/error-solutions/smtp-error-421/ . Also could be blocking from the otherside. What kind of email providers are returning emails ? Gmail , yahoo ? or they are domain related ?

Comment: I did a look up of the domain mxlookup.com and got this:                                      0 {domain}-com.mail.protection.outlook.com 104.47.51.110
Microsoft Corporation (AS8075) 60 min Blacklist Check      SMTP Test         
                                                                                                                                    
10 inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 54.240.248.234
 Amazon.com, Inc. (AS16509) 60 min Blacklist Check      SMTP Test                                 They are using outlook for their email. Their emails are through their domain

Comment: One quick test is to use any gmail,yahoo and send a test message to one of those emails and see if returns. That will confirm the issue is on the otherside ?